# In HTML5 can you use multiple div tags with class in a nested formation

Tags: html

Can you use more than 2 div tags with class inside of another div tag with class?
The way I used the div tags just don't seem to function properly.
Like,

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
}

.text1 {
  color: purple;
  line-height: 365px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: slategray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
  <div class="box3">
    <p class="text1">First Box.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box-2">
  <p>Second Box.</p>
</div>
```

I can not just use those box1, box3, and text1 in a single nested form.
Can I actually use it? Help me out...

Comment: Your markup is valid. But... `box3` ≠ `box-3`

Comment: I totally missed it... I actually use box1,2,3 not box-1,2,3... Oh man, I'm feeling so awkward right now...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You named your class wrong in css.

In css you wrote `box-3`, but in HTML the class is `box3`.

Here is the correct version (You cant see ,,First box,, text fully, because you set that box3 div will only be 50px wide).

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
}

.text1 {
  color: purple;
  line-height: 365px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: slategray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
  <div class="box3">
    <p class="text1">First Box.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box-2">
  <p>Second Box.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Uh.... Totally missed it..... I feel so... Sorry man, I'm a noobie...

Comment: Nothing to feel sorry about man, happened to me all the time when I started coding, still does. :) Let me know if you need any help !

Comment: This question was caused by a typo and can be closed as such - or deleted. Also, suggesting a totally new *undashed* class, even given there are already other two with dashes... is a bit strange.

Comment: I agree, should be box-3, instead of box3, my mistake.